# Change Nearest Class when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use jquery/javascript to change the class of the `<span class="thm-card-status">Active</span>` when the item is checked/unchecked. There will be a lot of `<div class="thm-card"></div>` containers so it should only be changed for that specific card.

```
  <div class="thm-card">
    <div class="thm-card-media">
      <img id="editableimage1" src="https://thehomemag.com/Images/HomeSlider/8.jpg" alt="#" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="thm-card-overlay">
        <form class="thm-form">
          <div class="form-group"><!--Default Checkbox Item-->
            <label for="__FOR__">
              <input type="checkbox" class="square thm-checkbox-status" id="__ID__" type="checkbox" value="true">
              <span class="thm-form-label-side">Active</span>
            </label>
            <a href="#" title="What is this?" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="You can make this slide active by checking this option." data-trigger="hover" class="thm-text-link-default"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form><!--Form-->
      </div>
      <span class="thm-card-status">Active</span>

    </div>
    <div class="thm-card-content">
      <div class="thm-card-details">
        <h4>THM Slider Main</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="thm-card-control">
      <div class="thm-card-links">
        <a href="#" class="thm-text-link-card" title="View">View</a>
        <a href="#" class="thm-text-link-card" onclick="return launchEditor('editableimage1', 'https://thehomemag.com/Images/HomeSlider/8.jpg');">Edit</a>
        <span class="thm-card-info"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
        <span class="thm-card-info"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT:**
I've tried:

```
$('.thm-checkbox-status').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.thm-card-status').attr('checked', '').closest('.thm-card-status').addClass('thm-card-status-active');
    } else {
        $('.open_sub_ja').closest('div').removeClass('someclass');
    }
});
```

And

```
$("thm-checkbox-status:checkbox").on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest('.thm-card-status').attr('class', 'thm-card-status-active');;
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service...you try, find issues, we can help! Please read the help section on how to ask a question

Comment: i've tried $("input:checkbox.thm-checkbox-status").change(function(){
  $(this).closest(".thm-card-status").toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
});

Comment: I've also tried $('.thm-checkbox-status').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.thm-card-status').attr('checked', '').closest('.thm-card-status').addClass('thm-card-status-active');
    } else {
        $('.open_sub_ja').closest('div').removeClass('someclass');
    }
});

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting code in comments!

Comment: You mean toggle a class? `$('.thm-checkbox-status').change(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('thm-card-status-active');
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example. I made the `thm-card-status-active` green, so that you can see it work.

```js
$(function() {

  $('input.thm-checkbox-status').change(function() { 
    
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
      $(this).closest('div.thm-card').find('span.thm-card-status').addClass('thm-card-status-active'); 
    } else {
      $(this).closest('div.thm-card').find('span.thm-card-status').removeClass('thm-card-status-active'); 
    }
    
  });

});
```

```css
.thm-card-status-active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thm-card">
    <div class="thm-card-media">
      <img id="editableimage1" src="https://thehomemag.com/Images/HomeSlider/8.jpg" alt="#" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="thm-card-overlay">
        <form class="thm-form">
          <div class="form-group"><!--Default Checkbox Item-->
            <label for="__FOR__">
              <input type="checkbox" class="square thm-checkbox-status" id="__ID__" type="checkbox" value="true">
              <span class="thm-form-label-side">Active</span>
            </label>
            <a href="#" title="What is this?" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="You can make this slide active by checking this option." data-trigger="hover" class="thm-text-link-default"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form><!--Form-->
      </div>
      <span class="thm-card-status">Active</span>

    </div>
    <div class="thm-card-content">
      <div class="thm-card-details">
        <h4>THM Slider Main</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="thm-card-control">
      <div class="thm-card-links">
        <a href="#" class="thm-text-link-card" title="View">View</a>
        <a href="#" class="thm-text-link-card" onclick="return launchEditor('editableimage1', 'https://thehomemag.com/Images/HomeSlider/8.jpg');">Edit</a>
        <span class="thm-card-info"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
        <span class="thm-card-info"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thm-checkbox-status').change(function(){
     $(this).closest('.thm-card-overlay').next().addClass('something');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I'm using iCheck (http://icheck.fronteed.com/) to handle the checkboxes. Will that affect it?